# How to get consolidated report of project mile stones for all projects in Redmine

Tags: redmine

We are Redmine as a Project management tool. It has been working great and we are happy with it. We now have a new requirement now. Our management wants to see a report showing each project's delivery date, manager, start date, total issues, open issues, closed issues. I searched at several places for quite some time and did not get a solution. I appreciate if someone can offer help.

Answer (score 0):

This is, for me personally, the single thing JIRA is better at :)
Anyway, that being said, you can get a summary of all open versions on your "my page", eh, page, by using this plugin:
https://github.com/bradbeattie/redmine-my-widgets-plugin

And you can also add custom queries to "my page".

Comment: This is not helping. When I add open versions to my page, I am getting the error and my page is becoming unusable. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which version of redmine and my widgets are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 1.0.1 of Redmine. I do not know the version of my widgets. I am using the one from https://github.com/edavis10/redmine-my-widgets.

Comment: You'll have to look at the error and maybe at the error logs too.

Answer (score 0):

You can get much of what you want in the issue report. Click the Summary button in the sidebar of the issues page in each project. [Example](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/issues/report)

Comment: We are aware of this. We do not want to go to individual project and check there. We want to see the snapshot of the project's status for all projects at one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Create one generic top level project. Calendar, gantt charts, issues, etc, for the top level project will show everything for every project that's nested underneath.

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly adding roadmaps/milestones to all the projects, you can use My Roadmaps plugin to get a consolidated visibility:

http://www.redmine.org/plugins/my_roadmaps

It works fine with 1.2 and 1.4 versions.